# Editing of revision's title is not applied

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, edit-summary

I edited a question and made a typo on the revision's title itself.

When trying to edit this revision to fix this typo in the revision's title, the update is not applied when clicking on `Save Edits` button.

---

I am not sure about filling a bug report here, do not hesitate to point it out if I am mistaken.

Comment: Is this about this revision: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62346635/revisions ?

Comment: Are you talking about attempting to change the edit summary field? When you change the edit summary field, you need to also make a change to post itself, otherwise the edit summary will just remain what it was before you opened up the edit window again. Is that what you're describing?

Comment: That is exactly what I am describe. 

I think it's a shame we cannot edit the summary field only: I have here a perfectly valid use case, to my sense.